# Shell comparing files

Tags: shell, command-line, diff, text-processing

This is my baseline values in a file named `file.txt`:

```
us-east-1a m1.small 1
us-east-1c m1.small 1
us-east-1c m3.medium 1
us-east-1c m3.medium 1
us-east-1c t1.micro 1
us-east-1d m1.large 1
us-east-1d m1.medium 1
us-east-1e m3.medium 6
```

This is the new file generated `file2.txt`:

```
us-east-1a c3.large 1
us-east-1a m1.small 7
us-east-1a m3.medium 6
us-east-1c m1.small 1
us-east-1c m3.medium 6
us-east-1c t1.micro 1
us-east-1d m1.large 1
us-east-1d m1.medium 1
us-east-1d m3.large 1
us-east-1d t2.medium 1
us-east-1e m3.medium 23
```

I am reframing my desired output . Can I get the exact output like below.

```
us-east-1a c3.large 1
us-east-1a m3.medium 6
us-east-1d m3.large 1
us-east-1d t2.medium 1
```

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: Hey martin thanks could you help me with sample script.

Comment: I tried using
temp=0;
while read line
do
 echo $line > temp1.txt
 while read line2
 do
  echo $line2 > temp2.txt
  diff temp1.txt temp2.txt > temp3.txt
  compare=`cat temp3.txt | wc -l | head -1`
  if [ "$compare" -eq 0 ];
  then
   temp=1; 
  fi
 done < file2.txt
 if [ "$temp" -eq 1 ];
 then
   cat $line2
 fi
done < file1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the first two fields compared and if they differ the line should be printed:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2];next}!($1$2 in a)' file.txt file2.txt
```

The first file `file.txt` is read in an array. And when the second file is processed the array contents are compared.

Comment: Thanks Chaos . This is what i expected